# Nothing is getting written to file

Tags: c, file, fwrite, getchar

Code:

```
struct subscriber
{
char phonenumber[20];
char name[50];
float amount;
}s;

void addrecords()
{
  FILE *f;
  char test;
  f=fopen("file.txt","ab+");
  //if(f==0)
  //{   f=fopen("file.txt","wb+");
    //system("clear");
    //printf("please wait while we configure your computer");
    //printf("/npress any key to continue");
    //getchar();
    //getch();
  //}

  while(1)
  {
    //system("clear");
    printf("\n Enter phone number:");
    scanf("%s",s.phonenumber);
    printf("\n Enter name:");
    fflush(stdin);
    //scanf("%[^\n]",s.name);

    scanf("%s",s.name);
    printf("\n Enter amount:");
    scanf("%f",&s.amount);
    printf("check 1");
    fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,f);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("check 2");
    //system("clear");
    printf("1 record successfully added");
    printf("\n Press esc key to exit, any other key to add other record:");
    test=getchar();
    //test=getche();
    if(test==27)
      break;
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

I am facing two problems here:

1. Nothing is getting written to file although file is being created.
2. After I enter the amount it outputs all the print statements and goes to the initial of the while loop that is it does not wait at getchar.

Answer (score 1):

The last `scanf()` doesn't read the newline at the end of the input, that's why `getchar()` returns immediately and doesn't wait and that's also the cause of the first problem, why the file isn't written, because you have to terminate the program to exit and the file isn't flushed. so you need to consume the newline char at the end of the last input you can do that with `scanf()`

```
scanf("%f%*[^\n]%*c",&s.amount);
```

Or using `fgets()` to read the whole line and using `scanf()` on that. Finally, note that you shouldn't use `fflush()` to clear an input stream, it's undefined:

> 7.19.5.2.2 If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function
>   causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host
>   environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Comment: Adding whitespace at the end of a `scanf` format string is generally not the best idea. The format `"%f\n"` scans in a `float` and then consumes all whitespace following that, so the `scanf` will not return before it encounters the next non-whitespace character after the `float`. It's better to clear the input buffer with a `getchar()` loop.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for pointing that out, I'd personally use fgets, but I didn't want to change scanf as the OP is using it, so I fixed the format instead.

Comment: Heh, that's the downside of `fgets`. You unlearn the traps of `scanf`. Oh, and you need `%*[^\n]` to suppress assignment of the stuff up to the newline.

Answer (score 0):

`fflush` is never necessary if you have `fclose`.

But in your case, you have `while(1)` and `fclose` outside, that means `fclose` never get called so the file content never gets updated by `fclose` function.

You might want to use `fflush` inside the loop, e.g. right after `fwrite`, then it will flush the buffer to actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You have named your file **file.txt**, so I assume you intend the file to be a text file? But then you open it with the **b** flag, which indicates binary format, and you write to it using **fwrite**, which doesn't convert the data to text, but just dumps the internal format to the file.

If you look at the created file in some sort of binary editor, you will see that it contains the data.